# I need a Magento page that can be used for quick purchasing by sku / product id and qty

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, product

In Magento, I need a page for buying product by using product sku or id and quantity.

For example, I want a page that have:

2 inputs and 1 submit button. One for entering product id/sku and one for entering product quantity. On submit it will take me to the Magento cart page for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the Magento Connect, there are few solutions, check this one http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fast-order-add-to-cart-by-sku-6156.html for instance.